# Datepicker 4.15.35 with Bootstrap 4.0.0

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap Datepicker 4.15.35 works well with Bootstrap 3.3.7, jQuery 1.11.0, and Moment 2.10.6.
But I would like to base my project on Bootstrap 4.0.0 and jQuery 3.1.1.

Does anyone now a combination that works?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go..

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group date">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help you good luck..

Comment: where to add $('#datepicker').datepicker(); in html page?? newvbie to javascript and jquery

Comment: add on bottom of your html page, before </body>

Comment: do you have any idea from where to learn javascript or jquery w3school are not much help.

Comment: according to me datetimepicker is a plugin isnot it??

Answer (score 0):

even this simple code will do:

```
<form action="/yourpage.php">
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That depends on the browser: [https://caniuse.com/#search=input-date](https://caniuse.com/#search=input-date)